# VBA: Userform Comboboxes (Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet)

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to set up a userform with multiple (7) comboboxes as drop down lists. I want some of the comboboxes to display the same list from my 'Lookuplists' sheet as they feed into different sections of a database.

I have used a similar code for a user form with 1 combo box with success, but I just keep getting the

> Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet error

as soon as I have more than 1 combobox. Any help or advice is much appreciated!

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cMeal As Range
Dim cSPFC As Range
Dim cSPMT As Range
Dim cKFFC As Range
Dim cKFMT As Range
Dim cPMFC As Range
Dim cPMMT As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")

For Each cMeal In ws.Range("Meal")
    With Me.cbMeal
        .AddItem cMeal.value
    End With
Next cMeal

For Each cSPFC In ws.Range("FluidConsistency")
    With Me.cbSPFC
        .AddItem cSPFC.value
    End With
Next cSPFC

For Each cSPMT In ws.Range("MealTexture")
    With Me.cbSPMT
        .AddItem cSPMT.value
    End With
Next cSPMT

For Each cKFFC In ws.Range("FluidConsistency")
    With Me.cbKFFC
        .AddItem cKFFC.value
    End With
Next cKFFC

For Each cKFMT In ws.Range("MealTexture")
    With Me.cbKFMT
        .AddItem cKFMT.value
    End With
Next cKFMT

For Each cPMFC In ws.Range("FluidConsistency")
    With Me.cbPMFC
        .AddItem cPMFC.value
    End With
Next cPMFC

For Each cPMMT In ws.Range("MealTexture")
    With Me.cbPMMT
        .AddItem cPMMT.value
    End With
Next cPMMT

End Sub
```

Comment: To fill ComboBox control you may use `.RowSource` method instead, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.rowsource)

Comment: I guess the error would come from your named ranges not being present on "LookupLists" sheet.

Comment: On which line do you get an error? have you checked if you didn't misspell the name of the range?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone! I ended up taking an .AddItem approach for each option in the ComboBox, as there was only a small number of set options for each list, and this way kept it nice and simple.